# Passing code with a value in a query string appended to the URL in JavaScript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been looking through different answers to what might be the same question I am asking, and a lot of the solutions have used PHP or JQuery and I have to do this in JavaScript.
Here is my problem (and I'm a real noob, so I'm probably doing something really stupid and that's why it's not working).

I am trying to pass 'code' with a value in a query string appended to the URL. Then get the code to write dynamically to the page after. 
Right now, I'm receiving the error: "Incorrect code submitted". I don't think I am sending the "code" correctly.

I started a jsfiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/shannongmac/6Z7NR/

Here is my code:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://florence.ccs.uconn.edu/~adepalma/cgi-bin/iskm3120/response.cgi",true);
            xmlhttp.send("yowza");

        function addText() {
        var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
        newParagraph.textContent = textArea.value;
        document.getElementById("myDiv").insertBefore(newParagraph, H2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The request is not completed due to javascripts same-origin policy ?

Comment: I'm just getting: Incorrect code submitted (that is the error in dreamweaver, I should say). It's not doing anything when I load in Chrome to try it.

Comment: I'm getting a same-origin error -> http://jsfiddle.net/6Z7NR/1/

Comment: But pasting the url `http://florence.ccs.uconn.edu/~adepalma/cgi-bin/iskm3120/response.cgi?name=yowza` into the browser it returns "incorrect code", and that's the API, so you're doing something wrong ?

Comment: This was the code we were given in the assignment, but I see what you are saying, so if it's not accepting it at all, is the code itself wrong?

Comment: Nope, the API your contacting does not support CORS, could be it supports JSONP, who knows ?

Comment: Ok (yes, I had to Google that!) I emailed my teacher, hopefully I can get to the bottom of it! Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code:

- You're trying to sent POST data when doing a GET request.  Try including your "yowsa" string as part of the url, rather than sending it as POST data.  Here's a quick intro to the difference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
- You need to send the correct key with your value.  Your commented out code shows that you tried "name=yowza.xmp".  It looks like you need "code=yowza".  (A bit of clever googling turns up http://florence.ccs.uconn.edu/~adepalma/cgi-bin/iskm3120/response.cgi?code=yowza as the correct request you need to make.  I'm not sure if that counts as cheating because I haven't seen the assignment).
- Whilst your requests may work in dreamweaver, you're going to face a problem on the real web, because you're making a request to a different domain.  Have a look into Cross-Origin Resource Sharing to find out more: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Ok, thank you.
fixed the URL and you are correct it works testing it in Dreamweaver, however I still get the same error when I run it through any browser, which is most likely what everyone has said that it is a CORS problem.